# i've had a error that import t as turtle. what do i do?

Tags: python

#### The Code:

```
import random
import turtle as t
```

#### Error:

```
File "gg.py", line 2, in <module>
    import turtle as t
```

Does anyone know what to do with this error?

Comment: Did you pip install turtles?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to import turtle as itself

ex:
import turtle
import random
import turtle as t

File "gg.py", line 2, in 
    import turtle as t

Comment: This answer is *incorrect*.  The OP's code is *fine as-is*.  There's something beyond the OP's code that isn't working correctly.